# Update ListView via AsyncTask or IntentService

Tags: android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to Update my Custom ListView which is fed by two String Arrays:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


    setupListView();

}

private void setupListView() {
    listItemList = new ArrayList();
    if (mParam1 != null && mParam2 != null && mParam1.length == mParam2.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mParam1.length; i++) {
            listItemList.add(new MyListItem(mParam1[i], (mParam2[i]).substring(0, 75) + "..."));
        }
    } else {
        listItemList.add(new MyListItem("Loading...", "Swipe Down for Update"));
    }

    mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), listItemList);
}
```

mParam1 and mParam2 are Values which are fetched by an XML parser (IntentService) class in the MainActivity which i can show if needed.

Now, if i am to fast, and the mPara1 and mPara2 is empty there won´t be any ListView shown. Now i want to solve this by some AsyncTask or IntentService whatever is useful. I tried AsyncTask, which didn´t work at all. I tried notifyDataSetChanged() which didn´t work too...

Now, how could i solve this....

Using AsyncTask i have the problem that i don´t know how to passt the two Arrays to publishProgress() correctly

THis is how my AsyncTask looks like:

```
 class UpdateListView extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


        private MyListAdapter adapter;
        private ArrayList listItemList;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            adapter = (MyListAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (String item1 : mParam1) {
                publishProgress(item1);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            adapter.add(new MyListItem(values[0], values[1]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.d("onPostExecute", "Added successfully");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it...My Fragments are running in same Activity where the Data is loaded in, so i just created getter and setter in MainActivity and access them in the needed Fragment via

```
String[] titles =(MainActivity) getActivity()).getTitlesArray();
String[] text=(MainActivity) getActivity()).getTextArray();
```

Whatever i do trying setting Bundle with

```
bundle.putStringArray(TITLES,titles);
```

doesn´t work. Should work using parceable/serializable class but didn´t try...